# Android Https Connection with self signed certificate : hostName not verified

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, ubuntu-12.04

Hi I am testing Android connecion with certificate.
I have created a default ssl server on my ubuntu desktop. Enabled ssl and created the default self-signed certificate. I have then connected to `https://localhost` with firefox, added certificate to exceptions and then I used Firefox to save cerificate as .pem file.
I added certificate.pem to my android projetc in res/raw

I have gotten this code from android developer website to connect via https using my certificate (I don't want to trust everything I just want to verify if certicate is correct using the certificate in raw folder).

So when I connect I get:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Hostname '192.168.1.111' was not verified

Here is the class I use to verify the certificate

```
public class VerifyKey extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    public static final String CERTIFICATE_TYPE_X_509 = "X.509";
    public static final String CERTIFICATE_ALIAS = "user_desktop";
    public static final String SERVER_URL = "https://192.168.1.111";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        InputStream certificateInputStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.user_desktop);
        Certificate certificate = null;
        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance(CERTIFICATE_TYPE_X_509);
            certificate = cf.generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);
            Log.d(TAG, "Certificate : " + certificate.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Certificate public key : " + certificate.getPublicKey());
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (certificateInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    certificateInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            if (keyStore != null) {
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry(CERTIFICATE_ALIAS, certificate);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("KeyStore is null");
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
        try {
            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            if (tmf != null) {
                tmf.init(keyStore);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("TrustManagerFactory is null");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        URL url = null;
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection =
                null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            Log.d(TAG, "URL : "+url.toString());
            httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket factory : "+socketFactory.toString());
            httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);

            in = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream(); //IOException exception gets triggered here

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), in.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SSLHandshakeException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(UnknownHostException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ConnectException e1){
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have gotten this code from http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned

I get this error on Samsung Galaxy s4 with Android 4.3

I don't have a lot of experience with HTTPS so here what I would like to achieve is povide certificate with the app which will allow to verify the server certificate. 
Please if someone can suggest what I can modify in the code.

I also have a doubt because my server is a .local server but I connect using ip and the objective is to be able to connect using both ip a hostname, will that be problem when veryfying the hostname?
Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT: I have added code to get the hostname:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_URL);
String hostName = addr.getHostName();
```

I have tried using the hostname instead of ip but still I get the same exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Hostname '<user.hostname.com>' was not verified
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:223)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:446)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem, it was actually a problem with the certificate:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/ssl
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
```

copy /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem somewhere else, change permissions of it to 777 (???)
and then add new apache.pem to res/raw folder of the app

then in common name field I have set the FQDN of my server such as host.name.com, I then updated the cerificate and key settings in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

All this thanks to site https://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/ssl-guides/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

Comment: in windows what is solution?

Comment: sorry I don't use windows so don't know, you should create a new post as your problem may be completely different than mine. Also beware that in Android sometimes ip addresses are "refused" so you should provide your own hostname verifier